# The output of giving Query

Tags: sql-server, query

```
WITH NumberSequence AS
(
SELECT
1 AS Number1
, 2 AS Number2
UNION ALL
SELECT
Number2 * 2 + 1
, Number1 * 5
FROM NumberSequence
WHERE Number1 < 200
)
SELECT
*
FROM NumberSequence

Number1 Number2
   1       2
   5       5
   11      25
   51      55
   111     255
   511     555
```

I don't understand why its giving this output. Why we just don't multiply Number1 with 5. Why we swap the process between numbers. Can somebody explain to me please.

I found this question in the final exam of the past years. But I don't understand how the result turned out like this. Shouldn't the result of column Number1 continue like 1-5-25-125? and the result of the number2 column should be in the form of 2-5-11-23, right? step by step, I want to know where what process is taking place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| Number1 | Number2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2*2+1=5 | 1*5=5 |
| 5*2+1=11 | 5*5=25 |
| 25*2+1=51 | 11*5=55 |
| ... | ... |

Every next step uses the result values from the previous line.

> why we are doing *2+1 operation on number1 instead of number2? It says Number2 * 2 + 1, Number1 * 5

Number2 has value `2` (on the first line), The expression (**for Number1**) is `Number2 * 2 +1`, so: `2 * 2 + 1`